# What is the resolution value of a chained Promise if a then handler doesn't return anything?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

If a `then` handler has no `return` statement, the resulting chained promise takes on the value `undefined` in bluebird.  But I cannot see anywhere that it is specified in Promises/A+ or anywhere?  Can this behavior be counted on?

Here's a test program:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');

var p = Promise.resolve('test');

p.then(function(s) {
    console.log('s1='+s);
    // no return
}).then(function(s) {
    // bluebird prints "undefined".  is this specified by a standard?
    console.log('s2='+s);
});
```

Comment: If any function returns nothing, or simply does not explicitly return, the value that is returned is `undefined`. This is normal Javascript behaviour, and has nothing to do with Promises.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Promises/A+ specifies to use the *return value* of a callback to resolve the promise.

Every function call that doesn't `throw` an exception (that has a "normal completion", in spec terms) does have such a return value. If a function execution doesn't encounter a *`return` statement*, this value will be `undefined`. This is made explicit in the spec in [section 9.2.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-function-objects-call-thisargument-argumentslist).

Comment: Thanks for the link.  For some reason I thought a caller could tell the difference in javascript between a void return and an explicit `return undefined` but it's clearly not the case as per the spec.

Comment: For that matter, also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20915450/why-javascript-functions-always-return-a-value) answers it pretty effectively.

Answer (score 2):

That is an expected behaviour and would happen even if you don't use **bluebird**. If you don't explicitly resolve with a value, the value is undefined, as is typical in JS.

Refer [this](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/async%20&%20performance/ch3.md#failing-to-pass-along-any-parametersenvironment) link to the book "[You Don't know JS](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/async%20&%20performance/ch3.md#failing-to-pass-along-any-parametersenvironment)". It explains it nicely.