# What's the value proposition for ESLint's "consistent return" rule?

Tags: javascript, eslint

What's the value of always returning a value ("undefined") for functions don't need to explicitly return anything?

Why is this a rule and what bugs does it catch?

---

You can read about ESLint's "consistent return" rule [here](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/consistent-return) (answers the "what", not the "why").

You can read a speculative analysis of why [javascript functions implicitly returns undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20915450/why-javascript-functions-always-return-a-value) here on stack overflow.

Comment: The value is knowing that all known paths out of the method will return something. It is a safety check.

Comment: @epascarello Thanks for taking the time to leave a comment!

Here's where I'm confused with your answer, though.  Javascript compiler already always add "return undefined" if you don't specify.  How does explicitly writing this improve the codebase?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some languages draw distinction between functions and procedures. This isn't the case in C-alikes, but it's still a good idea to design subroutines this way.

The linter doesn't want you to "always returning something". It just tells you that if you design a *function* (as opposed to a *procedure*), it has to return something meaningful in any case (ideally, all returned values must be of the same type).

Example:

```
function is_visible(object)
```

is a function, it should return a value (a boolean in this case) and can be used in expressions. On the other side

```
function make_visible(object)
```

is a procedure, it shouldn't return anything and cannot be used in expressions - it's always a statement.

Such a design (and the related linter warning) greatly helps to prevent bugs like this (taken from some random internet page):

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this definitely helps.