# Using void(0) when function doesn't return anything

Tags: javascript

Why isn't a good practice put void(0) when a function doesn't return anything explicitly?

```
function someFunc(a) {
  // do some stuffs
  return void(0);
}
```

This would help very much when debugging stuffs.

Thanks.

Comment: I could be oversimplifying, but `void(0)` evaluates as `undefined`. A function that is defined without an explicit return statement (or simply `return;`) implicitly returns `undefined` anyway, so, the explicit return is redundant. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20915450/why-javascript-functions-always-return-a-value.

Comment: yeap, but i don't think this is redundant, cause would be debugging, don't u think? functions always return something, so this would help, i don't know, maybe i'm wrong.

Comment: `function someFunc(a) { }` and `function someFunc(a) { return; }` and `function someFunc(a) { return void(0); }` are all functionally equivalent. I think once you know that's how it works, you can comfortably stick with the shortest version, with no explicit return statement.

Comment: would be a bad thing use void(0) to helping in debug? i think it really helps.

Comment: *void* is an operator, not a function, so the brackets are redundant, `void 0` is sufficient. It's used as a short way to write "undefined", but in a return statement it's pointless as a return statement without a value returns *undefined* anyway.

Comment: @D_REIS: Show me an example; I'm not convinced. There's no point in explicitly writing out what the JavaScript compiler is automatically going to compile into your functions for you.

Comment: @Cory, exactly. @RobG, both `void 0` and `void(0)` are valid syntax.

Comment: @Himmel—I didn't say it was invalid syntax, just pointless use of a grouping operator, like `x = (1 + 2);`

Comment: I see, that's right.

Comment: "*when a function doesn't return anything explicitly?*" - because if you want to **implicitly** return undefined, you shouldn't explicitly `return` *anything*.

Answer (score 0):

Since `void(0)` resolves to `undefined`, the question could just as well be "why isn't it a good idea to return `undefined` from a function?". Using `void(0)` as an alternative to `undefined` is probably a bad idea, relatively speaking, because it's more complex than `undefined`, and less explicit. Our goal as programmers is to make simple, readable code for others to read and make sense of.

It's a bad idea to explicitly return `undefined` from a function for the same reason, it introduces unnecessary complexity. `typeof undefined` evaluates to `undefined`. This makes writing tests more difficult and gives you less insight into the purpose of a function than does, say, returning `false`.

Comment: I'm not condoning its usage, but I think one reason `void(0)` exists is to always return a true `undefined`, since in some contexts you can override the value of `undefined`.

Comment: i think you are wrong Himmel, is better to use void(0) because of incompatible issues with older browsers with undefined, like Cory said.

Comment: `void(0)` is equivalent to `undefined` when you are returning a value. If either of those are assigned to a variable, well, both of those can be overwritten by any value.

Comment: @D_REIS, your statement contradicts itself and makes the case in my favor. You should use `undefined` because older browsers are incompatible with it..?

Comment: `typeof undefined` returns the string "undefined", not the undefined value.

Comment: @RobG where did I indicate otherwise?

Comment: @Himmel—where you said "`typeof undefined` evaluates to `undefined`". It doesn't, it evaluates to the string "undefined". E.g. `if (typeof undefined)` always resolves to true since the string "undefined" is truthy.

Comment: Both make for poor function design, in my opinion.