# Not getting an error for following implementation of Interface in Typescript

Tags: typescript

The return type of method 'move()' in Interface Person is void

```
interface Person {
     name: string;
     age?: number;
     move(): void;
 }
```

while in function definition move() method is returning a number

```
var  p: Person = {
    name: 'something',
    move: () => { return 8; },
}
```

Should I not get an error in Typescript ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems weird, but it also makes sense.

First thing first: javascript function always return, if no explicit return statement was used then it automatically `return undefined`, you can read more about it in [Why JavaScript functions always return a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20915450/why-javascript-functions-always-return-a-value) and [Does every Javascript function have to return a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17337064/does-every-javascript-function-have-to-return-a-value).
So even when you say that your function returns `void`, it actually returns `undefined`.

There's no conflict with returning a number even though the interface declared void, because if you'll do this:

```
let a = p.move() + 1;
```

You'll get:

> Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'void' and 'number'

because `p` is defined to be a `Person`.
But even this is fine:

```
class MyPerson implements Person {
    name = "name";
    age = 8;
    move(): number {
        return this.age;
    }
}

let p1 = new MyPerson();
let p2: Person = new MyPerson();

let a1 = p1.move() + 1; // fine
let a2 = p2.move() + 1; // same error as before
```

In this case, if you have a `Person` then `move` returns a `void`, if you have a `MyPerson` then it returns a number.

Why this happens is because it's safe to return a value even if the interface declares that it should be void, which is why your object and my class satisfy the contract defined by the interface.
It's safe because if someone is using your code (or the IDE) he thinks that object who implement the interface returns void, the fact that the function will later return a value at runtime won't change anything (the compiler will error if you'll treat the function as returning a value).

On the other hand if it was the other way around:

```
interface Person {
     name: string;
     age?: number;
     move(): number;
}

var p: Person = {
     name: 'something',
     move: (): void => {  }
}
```

You get an error saying that the object isn't assignable to type `Person`.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on Nitzan's answer, then perhaps it be assumed that implementing an interface with a function that returns void is meaningless since every function is supposed to return something whether it be undefined, a string, num, obj etc.

```
interface Person{
   move():void //meaningless type declaration}
```

is the same as

```
interface Person{
   move()}
```