# JS function with jquery always return undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, return-value

I am building a Js function with Jquery checking if certain inputs are empty or not for validation. Here's the function that checks if the inputs are empty or not:

```
   function isValid(elements){
      var validation = false
      elements.each(function() {
        if ($( this ).val().length > 0){
          validation = true
        }
        else {
          validation
        }
      });
      validation
    }
```

however whatever I do my function returns undefined and never the boolean value that is supposed to be contained in the validation variable ?

What should I do for my function to return true or false ?

Comment: What are you passing into for elements?

Comment: You are not at all returning anything from the function.

Comment: What do you think `validation` lines are doing? Your logic is also flawed. The validation is most likely not doing what you want it to do.

Comment: indeed I thought the my last validation was returning my boolean value but now I understand I need to use return

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return false if at least one element is empty, otherwise return true.

```
function isValid(elements){
  var validation = true;

  elements.each(function() {
    if ($( this ).val().trim().length === 0){
      validation = false;
    }
  });

  return validation;
}
```

Comment: return false inside of `each` would act as a breaking statement

Comment: You may also want to add a `trim()` in the length check, otherwise filling the field with spaces would be valid

Answer (score 2):

Your function `isValid()` is returning undefined because this is the expected behaviour in JavaScript: undefined is the “default” returned value if a function does not specify one returned value, and your function `isValid()` doesn't have any return.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20915524/5768908).

Answer (score 2):

You can do your code like below by using `Array#some`,

```
function isValid(elements) {
 return !Array.from(elements).some(function(itm){ itm.value.trim().length == 0 });
}
```

You are not at all returning anything from the function, that means as a default returning value `undefined` will be returned.