# Why do Javascript functions return "undefined" on creation?

Tags: javascript

I understand the difference between undefined and null as a type; I'm just not grasping the following event:

```
function x() {
    return 0;
}

undefined
```

Why does this happen? What is going on under the hood that is causing the environment to return an "undefined" value?

UPDATE: I'm not invoking the function in the example above, just defining it and the console returns this "undefined" value.

Comment: where do you get `undefined`? in the console maybe?

Comment: When you call this function, it return undefined instead of 0 ?

Comment: You should call/console the function as `console.log( x() );` and not as `console.log( x );` . I am just assuming here :)

Comment: I think he refers to the console. When you just declare the function.

Comment: @eisbehr I think he tried this in console and means at the time of declaration

Comment: @Eddie — `console.log( x )` would give *the function* and not `undefined`

Comment: @Quentin.. Ohh yeah. You are right. My bad :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This fuction definition is a statement. In JS, statements don't return values, which, in JS, is an `undefined` value.

In JS, assignments with `var` are statements too, but assignments without `var` behave as expressions : their whole value is the value being assigned.

Therefore, in the console :

```
> x=function() {return 0;}
< ƒ () {return 0;}
```

Comment: Okay, thank you. So if I understand correctly, Javascript always wants a return from every statement and command?

Comment: Yes you can see it as such : in JS a statement can be used in place of an expression, and its value will be `undefined` (which makes it pretty useless in that place).

Comment: undefined is the implicit return type in js, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/20915520/2455159

Answer (score 2):

> What is going on under the hood that is causing the environment to return an "undefined" value?

In this case, `undefined` represents the lack of a value.

You haven't run any expression, so there is no value to arise from it.