# recursive function: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: python, recursion, nonetype

I have a nested dictionary,

```
d={
    "A":1, 
    "depth":0, 
    "chain":[
        {
            "A1":0.7, 
            "depth":1,
            "chain":[
                {
                    "A11":0.3,
                    "depth":2,
                    "key2":{"direct":{},"cumulative":{"B":0.3}}, 
                    "chain":[]
                }, 
                {
                    "A12":0.4, 
                    "depth":2,
                    "chain":[
                        {
                            "A121":0.4, 
                            "depth":3, 
                            "key2":{"direct": {}, "cumulative":{"C":0.2, "D": 0.2}}, 
                           "chain": []
                        }]}]},
        {
            "A2":0.3,
            "depth":1,
            "chain":[
                {
                    "A11":0.3, 
                    "depth":2, 
                    "key2":{"direct":{}, "cumulative":{"D":0.3}},
                    "chain":[]
                }]}]}
```

I want to return a list that the first key is repeated by x times. x is the number of elements under "chain". In this case, it would return:

```
["A", "A", "A1", "A1", "A2", "A12"]
```

I have tried the following

```
def from_nodes(d):
    from_n=[list(d.keys())[0]]*len(d["chain"])
    for x in d["chain"]:
        if x is not None:
            from_n.extend(from_nodes(x))
            return from_n
```

and got the error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-196-6233463c604b>in <module>()
----> 1 from_nodes(test2)

<ipython-input-194-5b7ca4b6db75>in from_nodes(d)
  3     for x in d["chain"]:
  4         if x is not None:
----> 5             from_n.extend(from_nodes(x))
  6         return from_n

<ipython-input-194-5b7ca4b6db75> in from_nodes(d)
  3     for x in d["chain"]:
  4         if x is not None:
----> 5             from_n.extend(from_nodes(x))
  6         return from_n
```

Comment: What does your function return when all `x` in `d["chain"]` are `None`?

Comment: Please include the full traceback of the error.

Comment: If `d["chain"]` does not have anything to iterate, you never get into your `for` loop. Thus the function will return `None` You probably need to un-indent the `return from_n` line two times.

Comment: `got the error TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable` Edit your question to include the full error traceback.  You're making us guess where the error is happening.

Comment: @DyZ if `x` are `None`, it doesn't extend the list with anything.

Comment: @edge27 And returns `None`. Exactly my point.

Comment: Your error message now shows code that is not the same as your posting. Please correct your transcription errors. Python is sensitive to indentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50972304/recursive-function-nonetype-object-is-not-iterable/50976109#comment88941094_50972304), your error is that the return statement is indented incorrectly. If `d["chain"]` is empty or `None`, your function will [return `None` implicitly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1563100/5858851).

Changing your function to the following:

```
def from_nodes(d):
    from_n=[list(d.keys())[0]]*len(d["chain"])
    for x in d["chain"]:
        if x is not None:
            from_n.extend(from_nodes(x))
    return from_n
```

will fix the error and the result on my computer is:

```
print(from_nodes(d))
#['A', 'A', 'A1', 'A1', 'depth', 'depth']
```

Which doesn't match your desired output-- this is because you aren't guaranteed to get a deterministic order when you call `.keys()`.

One way to modify your function for the desired output would be to create a list of keys to ignore:

```
def from_nodes(d):
    ignore_keys = {"chain", "depth", "key2"}
    from_n=[list(k for k in d.keys() if k not in ignore_keys)[0]]*len(d["chain"])
    for x in d["chain"]:
        if x is not None:
            from_n.extend(from_nodes(x))
    return from_n

print(from_nodes(d))
#['A', 'A', 'A1', 'A1', 'A12', 'A2']
```

However, this is just me speculating what your requirements are. You need to define the correct condition for what you mean by the "first" key.

Comment: ['A', 'A', 'A1', 'A1', 'A12', 'A2'] is indeed my desired output, but the first solution you provided worked perfectly on my computer, without having a list of keys to ignore

Comment: What version of python? After 3.6, dictionaries maintain insertion order.